# Error in form collection MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying to add textbox values to DB using formcollection class but every time it is giving only one textbox value not other textboxes values. i'm sharing what i have done so far. please guide me

TEXTBOX in VIEW:

```
<input type="text" name="abcd" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber0" style="width:130px;" />
<input type="text" name="abcd" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber1" style="width:130px;" />
<input type="text" name="abcd" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber2" style="width:130px;" />
<input type="text" name="abcd" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber3" style="width:130px;" />
<input type="text" name="abcd" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber4" style="width:130px;" />
<input type="text" name="abcd" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber5" style="width:130px;" />
```

ActionMethod:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(FormCollection values)
        {    
                    var abc = values["abcd"].ToString();
                    var getID = await db.Parts.Where(c =>c.PartNumber==abc).FirstOrDefaultAsync();                            
                }
```

it is just saving the first textbox name "abcd" value to DB, but i want all textboxes values in DB, please guide me

Comment: can you show the view html for another text element in your form?

Comment: Where are the other textboxes?

Comment: @VahidND i have updated my question please check

Comment: @NeilThompson i have updated my question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because u r using Same Name 
Form Collection class reads the name of control 
use following code and u will get different value for different name of textbox

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Demo", "Admin"))
{
<input type="text" name="PartNumber0" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber0" style="width:130px;" />
<input type="text" name="PartNumber1" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber1" style="width:130px;" />
<input type="text" name="PartNumber2" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber2" style="width:130px;" />
<input type="text" name="PartNumber3" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber3" style="width:130px;" />
<input type="text" name="PartNumber4" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber4" style="width:130px;" />
<input type="text" name="PartNumber5" autocomplete="off" id="PartNumber5" style="width:130px;" />
<input type="submit" value="Click" />
}
```

thank you

Comment: thanks for the help, but how i can use these values in controller action method?

Comment: string a = formvalues["PartNumber0"];
            string b = formvalues["PartNumber1"];
            string c = formvalues["PartNumber2"];
            string d = formvalues["PartNumber3"];
            string e = formvalues["PartNumber4"];

this is how u can retrieve any formcollection values

Comment: It will work, but I suggest using a ViewModel instead of the FormCollection.